# ssrs 2008 hide tablix single column visibility false

Tags: ssrs-2008

Currently working with sql ssrs2008,
to set tablix single column visibility false,

Normally when I click on tablix header called "mrp", column visibility is in inactive mode so I am unable to click on it.

Otherwise, I clicked on tablix column header "MRP" and did changes in property called  `"hidden"` as `"=Parameters!ShowSummary.Value=True"`, but when I view the reports it show blank column with no data,

I need to hide that column so on screen or when I export output to Excel it should not show the blank column (white space)

Answer (score 0):

You are currently seeing a blank column due to the tablix borders, they are probably black or some non-white color.
You should refere the following solution at:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sqlreportingservices/thread/3f76a2a6-053a-4da4-8995-5e39f9571c65